# Structure theorem for finitely generated profinite abelian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, profinite-groups

Is there a structure theorem for finitely generated profinite abelian group like a structure theorem of f.g. abelian group?

Comment: The version as stated is clearly false as $\mathbf Z_p$ is not of this form. But I think that every finitely generated profinite abelian group is a product of its pro-$p$ Sylow subgroups, and each of those is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z_p^n \times H$ for $H$ a finite abelian $p$-group.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Yes. A f.g. profinite abelian group is the same as a profinite abelian group $G$ that is a quotient of $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}^d$ for some $d$. By Pontryagin duality, this is the same as a locally finite abelian group that is isomorphic to a subgroup of $(\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z})^d$ for some $d$. The latter is easy to classify: this is a direct sum of copies of Prüfer and its quotients, such that each prime appears $\le d$ times. So the classification is: $\prod_{p\text{ prime}}A_p$ with $A_p$ is a product of $\le d$ quotients of the $p$-adic group $\mathbf{Z}_p$ (with $d$ independent of $p$).

Comment: A reference is Ribes–Zalesskii's *Profinite groups*, §4.3. (Although it seems that they use Pontryagin duality between profinite abelian groups and torsion abelian groups in the proof, which should be unnecessary.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn yes, it's not really necessary, it's just a way for me to feel safer (performing the argument for the discrete dual) but definitely one can do everything at the profinite side.

Comment: Is it Smith normal form?